# Bootstrap 3: push/pull - bug or mobile first?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'd like to **change the order of** my `col-*` and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

I just switched the order of two Chars *(C & D)* to fix it, but it doesn't feel right. Is it because of ***"mobile first"*** or am I missing something?

**Goal**:

```
-------------------------
|    SIZE   |   ORDER   |
-------------------------
|   >= SM   |  A B C D  |
|    < SM   |  A B D C  | <- C & D are switching 
-------------------------
```

**My first approach and understanding (not working):**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">C</div> <!-- !!! -->
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Second approach (working, but unsure if correct):**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">D</div> <!-- !!! -->
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to markup as mobile first, and then apply the push and pull to the other sizes. Bootstrap is mobile-first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach is right, when you using `push class and pull class` the text will be shifting each other place. you are using `sm-push` & `sm-pull` so it will only effect in small device. if you want to mobile view u can use `xs-pull and xs-push`.